# using src working just fine unlike whats written in the tutorial

Tags: angularjs

What's the difference between `src` and `ng-src`? From the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_06) i read that:

> That directive prevents the browser from treating the Angular {{ expression }} markup literally

But when i tested it with using `<img src="{{phone.url}}">` - it worked just fine. 
I am using the latest angularJs version.

So what's the reason? the tutorial is outdated or am i missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it will work with `src` attribute. But by the time angular bootstraps and processes HTML, there will have already been issued an HTTP GET request with broken URL:

```
http://yourdomain.com/%7B%7Bphone.url%7D%7D
```

which is obviously going to be 404. To prevent this from happening you should use `ngSrc` directive which sets proper `src` as soon as all necessary variables are resolved. Once it's done browser starts downloading valid image resource.

Comment: The DOM is loaded in the browser _before_ the src attribute is parsed by Angular. When the browser sees an img it immediately attempts to retrieve the resource, giving a 404, as stated in the answer. Sure, this is quickly resolved when Angular kicks in and then the real image is retrieved. But there are problems. You don't want unnecessary requests and 404s in your app. And more importantly, if the client is slow there may be a flicker between initial load (with the missing image) and when Angular kicks in and loads the real image. This is definitely not wanted. Just use ng-src.